Cannot import path for folder and files added to MFC C++ project in Visual Studio 2015
i'm trying to add new folder and files to my MFC C++ project in Visual Studio 2015. however after added new folder and files, i'm unable to import/include the file path for use in other file.
here is how I created and added an existing file to new folder

furthermore, I tried to add the new file and its path to the Project.vcxproj as well
<ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="..\TCPS_RCP\RcpData\CSVFileHandler.h" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="..\Include\RcpData\CSVFileHandler.cpp" />
</ItemGroup>


however, when building the project, i still got the error such
Error  C1083   Cannot open source file: '..\Include\RcpData\CSVFileHandler.cpp': No such file or directory TCPS    D:\work\LGDVH_SBSB\Src\MS\SBSB_MS_TCPS_VH_RE2024041123_00_불합리 개선\TCPS\c1xx

What is the folder structure?
